# Add UTF8 collation to mail php?

Tags: php, email, utf-8, smtp

I successfully can send email from my smtp but i can't add the utf8 collation. This is my SendMail function:

```
    function SendMail ()
{
    if ($SMTPIN = fsockopen ($this->SmtpServer, $this->PortSMTP))
    {
        fputs ($SMTPIN, "EHLO ".$HTTP_HOST."\r\n");
        $talk["hello"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 );
        fputs($SMTPIN, "auth login\r\n");
        $talk["res"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
        fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpUser."\r\n");
        $talk["user"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
        fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpPass."\r\n");
        $talk["pass"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
        fputs ($SMTPIN, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->from.">\r\n");
        $talk["From"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 );
        fputs ($SMTPIN, "RCPT TO: <".$this->to.">\r\n");
        $talk["To"] = fgets ($SMTPIN, 1024);
        fputs($SMTPIN, "DATA\r\n");
        $talk["data"]=fgets( $SMTPIN,1024 );
        fputs($SMTPIN, "To: <".$this->to.">\r\nFrom: <".$this->from.">\r\nSubject:".$this->subject."\r\n\r\n\r\n".$this->body."\r\n.\r\n");

        $talk["send"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
        fputs ($SMTPIN, "QUIT\r\n");
        fclose($SMTPIN);

    }
    return $talk;
}
```

This is what i tried so far, but doesn't work for me.

```
fputs($SMTPIN, "To: <".$this->to.">\r\nCc:<".$this->cc.">\r\nFrom:<".$this->from.">\r\nSubject:".$this->subject."\r\n"."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nComments :".$this->body."\r\n.\r\n");
```

Comment: The entire application, from top to bottom, needs to be UTF-8. That includes PHP header, HTML header (if relevant), file-encoding, etc. Is the text UTF8 encoded before it goes through this function?

Comment: Yes, in html and php @Qirel

Comment: Can you verify that the data you get before sending the mail is in fact properly encoded? By printing/logging it?